# Weird Chance and Community Chest Cards

Tags: monopoly

I received a Monopoly set for Christmas, version C1009.
The Chance and Community Chest cards are non-standard. For instance, one instructs you to throw all the 100 dollar bills in the air.

Does anyone have a list of the Chance and Community Chest Cards that are accepted as the gold standard for tournament play?

Comment: In the 2018 version of Monopoly, Cash Grab is a Chance card that replaces the «Bank pays you dividend of $50» card https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2112669/2018-edition-new-cash-grab-chance-card

Answer (score 1):

The following website gives the list of cards for the American versions.

[List of Chance and Community Chest cards](https://monopolyguide.com/traditional/monopoly-list-of-chance-cards-main-version/)

If you are playing a version for another country, e.g. U.K. or Australia, the cards will differ. Also, tournaments must use officially licensed Hasbro Monopoly games.

For more details, there is a Wiki How to host an official Monopoly tournament:

[Wiki How to host a Monopoly tournament](https://www.wikihow.com/Host-an-Official-Monopoly-Tournament)